# How to draw paths for the islands in world map using d3.js

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js, d3.js, vue-events

I am facing an issue while doing d3.js maps, the issue is every country I am able to fill the color but coming to islands I am unable to see the islands places

```js
    attr("stroke", function(d){
                    console.log("stroke",d.properties.name_sort)
                var s = d.properties.name_sort+"";
                if(s.includes("Islands")){
                  return "#FF0000";
                }
              return "#fff";
              })
              .attr("stroke-width", function(d){    
                var s = d.properties.name_sort+"";        
                if(s.includes("Islands")){ 
                  return 2;
                }
              return 0.1;
              })
```

[image: please observe the image when I hard code it]

Comment: Which country are you particularly talking about?

Comment: Can you show what you have? Seeing neither your code nor your output, in addition to not knowing what islands, any attempt at an answer would likely be too speculative to be of use for you.

Comment: The total islands are not appearing in mapview, if I hard code like like   attr("stroke", function(d){
    var s = d.properties.name_sort+"";
    if(s.includes("Islands")){
      return "#FF0000";
    }
     return "#fff";
     })
     .attr("stroke-width", function(d){    
    var s = d.properties.name_sort+"";        
    if(s.includes("Islands")){ 
      return 2;
    }
     return 0.1;
     })

Comment: But as per the correct approach, we should not hard code.  can you help me out

Comment: @Chilarai we have a list of countries so we don't know how many countries having islands so in this scenario how to handle this kind of issue.

Comment: It's a difficult question - the islands are too small to be visible by fill alone. The simplest solution would be to give everything a stroke. If using topojson you could potentially find a way to add a stroke to islands (no matter their size, eg Greenland) only programmatically. Another approach might be to calculate the projected size of each polygon when drawing it (d3.geoBounds for example) and use that to either add a stroke, or replace the feature with a circle. Some of an answer would depend on how your data is structured. I could write an answer for the last option if it sounds useful

Comment: Thank you @AndrewReid I will try last option

Comment: I got this bounds (2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
0: Array(2)
0: -180
1: -90
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
1: Array(2)
0: 180
1: 90
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 2
  can you give me idea how to move forward now @AndrewReid

Comment: I'll be able to look tomorrow in greater detail, just headed to bed at the moment. If you could include a link to the geojson that would make an answer more useful, though this is not neccesary, you can strip data fields if they are sensitive.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are too many small land locked countries that are not visible (Luxembourg, Burundi, etc) that will also be included if scanning for rendered size. This might alter your desired outcome, so I haven't posted it.